# How to declare int in angular service file , Error : ["The value '0' is invalid."]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have to send a int value for `FlightClass` to Back end. And FlightClass is a optional field. so If I select none of this option I need to sent 0 (int type) as a value of `FlightCLass` field.

But In my case The value send as '0' (string type).

I got this error in network - `["The value '0' is invalid."]`

I have a enum.

```
export enum FlightClass {
    EconomyClass = 1,
    PremiumClass,
    BusinessClass,
    FirstClass,
}
```

service.ts

```
 resetForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
flightClass:  [0],
}
```

model.ts
`flightClassType: FlightClass;`

ts.file -

```
import { FlightClass} from '../../../enums/enquiries';
 flightClass = FlightClass;

 get dealForm() {
    return this.service.form;
  }

//inside the submitHandle()
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('flightClass', this.dealForm.get('flightClass').value);
```

.html file

```
<nb-radio-group name="flightClass" formControlName="flightClass" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                      <nb-radio [value]="flightClass.BusinessClass">Business Class</nb-radio>
                      <nb-radio [value]="flightClass.EconomyClass">Economy Class</nb-radio>
                      <nb-radio [value]="flightClass.FirstClass">First Class</nb-radio>
                      <nb-radio [value]="flightClass.PremiumClass">Premium Class</nb-radio>
                    </nb-radio-group>
```

Note:

When I try with

`formData.append( "flightClass", parseInt(this.dealForm.get("flightClass").value, 10) );`,

I got this error
`Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'`

Comment: What is formData? Can you add ur sample code on stackblitz

Comment: You need to add more details to the question. How are you getting form values? How are you sending it? Generally, form values are in string.

Comment: I put in .html `formControlName="flightClass" `, and I get the value like this `formData.append('flightClass', this.dealForm.get('flightClass').value);` 
If form value are string, then how to change to int.

Comment: The below will work well:
`formData.append('flightClass', this.dealForm.get('flightClass').value);`
You don't need to change it to int, just make sure the api service is having 'flightClass' property as a string that's it. it will automatically converted into integer at receiving end . let me know i can explain more in detail thanks

Comment: again error `["The value '' is invalid."]}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, but check if parseInt really returns a number.

```
formData.append('flightClass', JSON.stringify(Number(parseInt(this.dealForm.get("flightClass").value)));
```